# SQL Server union temp tables

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2016, temp-tables, union-all

I have a piece of SQL that takes a parameter, assesses the contents of the parameter and depending on the contents applies different UDF to the input parameter.

the code goes something like this:

```
declare @order varchar(50) = 's12345..s12347'

if  isnull( CHARINDEX('.',@order),0) >0 

begin

select  n as order_no into #temp 
 FROM F_GetAllNBetween(@order)

end

 else if ( isnull( CHARINDEX(',',@order),0) >0 )
    begin
        select [value] as order_no  into #temp2
         FROM  dbo.F_SplitList(@order,',') 

end
    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null
    select * from #temp  where order_no <>''

        if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') is not null
    select * from #temp2 where order_no <>''
```

what I want to do is, get the output from the above union into another temp table and use it in the where clause of the rest of the code.

I cannot use union as it errors saying a select is expected.

I cannot use cte as I cannot use the check to see if the temp tables are empty

I cannot ignore checking for empty temp tables else it errors saying object does not exist ( if statement only creates one of the two temp tables)

I cannot figure out how to get the output to a different temp table. Any ideas suggestions or better way of doing the same please?

Comment: the input parameter will only ever have a "." (full stop) or a "," (comma) in it

Comment: I think you could simplify the whole thing by removing the temporary tables, if I'm understanding it correctly. For example, `select order_no from (select n as order_no from f_getallnbetween(@order) where charindex('.', @order) > 0 union all select [value] from dbo.f_splitlist(@order, ',') where charindex(',' @order) > 0) as t where order_no <> '';`

Comment: @ZLK Doh! why didn't I think of that! Just goes to show how easy it is to get fixated on making a piece of code work. Write this as an answer and I could accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can simplify your current code to achieve what you want with a UNION and WHERE clauses to replace the IF statements. e.g.

```
SELECT order_no
--INTO #someTempTable -- if needed
FROM (
    SELECT order_no = n 
    FROM dbo.F_GetAllNBetween(@order)
    WHERE CHARINDEX('.', @order) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value
    FROM dbo.F_SplitList(@order,',') 
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', @order) > 0
) AS T
WHERE order_no <> '';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but out of curiosity.. if you do want to do what I originally wanted to do.. how can I do that please?

Comment: @Harry, I would create a temporary table (or use a table variable) and insert into that from #temp1 (if it exists) and #temp2 (if it exists). e.g. `DECLARE @T TABLE (order_no varchar(255)); IF OBJECT_ID(...) IS NOT NULL INSERT @T SELECT order_no` etc.